# Использование циклов в R

Tags: циклы, r, dataframe

есть необходимость применить вот такой фильтр к данным:

```
for (j in 1:n_filtra){
  for (i in 2:(nrow(data_point1)-1)){
    data_point1$x[i] <- (data_point1$x_filtred[i-1] + data_point1$x_filtred[i] + data_point1$x_filtred[i+1])/3
    data_point1$y[i] <- (data_point1$y_filtred[i-1] + data_point1$y_filtred[i] + data_point1$y_filtred[i+1])/3
  }
  data_point1$x_filtred <- data_point1$x
  data_point1$y_filtred <- data_point1$y
}
```

при такой реализации код работает очень медленно, насколько я понимаю через функции apply использовать элемент i+1, i-1 не получится. Есть ли какие-то другие способы написать этот код производительнее? Количество строк в датафрейме около 20000, количество итераций фильтра n_filtra = 10.

Comment: Приведите пример данных или код для генерации аналогичных по структуре.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить внутренний цикл на конструкцию вида:

```
DF[2:nrow(DF), "x"] <- RcppRoll::roll_mean(DF$x, n = 3)
```

Для `y` соответственно.